# populating dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, vb.net, drop-down-menu

[image]I have a web method that returns a list.

```
    <WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function populateDropdown(ByVal aptdate As Date, ByVal dentistid As Integer) As List(Of String)
    Dim apttime As New List(Of String)
    Try
        apttime = DatabaseLayer.GetAvailableAppointmentTime(aptdate, dentistid)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return apttime
End Function
```

End Class

I want to populate the dropdown with the above result set

I am using a jquery ajax function to do so.

```
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Appointment.aspx/populateDropdown",
                data: '{aptdate:' + '"' + aptdate + '"' + ',dentistid:' + '"' + dentistid + '"' + ' }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d.length);
                    var options = $("#drpdwnapttime");
                    $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                    alert(value);
                        options.append($("<option />").val(this.data).text(this.data));
                    });
                }
            });
```

However this dosen't seem to work. Value in the alert box is 11, so I assume I am geeting the arrays correctly. The alert in for each shows just one loop and then nothing happens.
I can't really figure out whats wrong here.
EDit:
Changed the code and
I added an Image of the alert I get inside the $.each. Should't I be getting just one value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. Thanks for all the suggestions I wouldn't have figured out other wise.

```
var resultData = data['d'];
$.each(resultData, function (key,value) {
alert(this);
options.append($("<option />").val(value).text(value));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) passes the key and the value to the callback:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    options.append($("<option />").val(value).text(value));
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I have uploaded the image of the alert box I get inside $.each. Shouldn't I get just one value.

Answer (score 0):

i think in below code

```
options.append($("<option />").val(this.data).text(this.data));
```

this.data will not work you have to see the property of data

like (data.somethingYourProperyname )

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass `data.d` to $.each(). And since `data.d` is the string array, `this` should be the string itself, not `this.data`...

```
$.each(data.d, function () {
    options.append($("<option />").val(this).text(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is a list use this to access that

```
$.each(data, function () {
    options.append($("<option />").val(this).text(this));
}
```